# Network Drive label

Tags: windows, networking, c#-2.0, label, drives

I'm trying to get the label of some network resources mapped as drives. When I use DriveInfo.GetDrives(), local volumes have the VolumeLabel filled parameter as expected, but in network drives it is an empty string. How can I get those labels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use WMI for this - not sure of the exact query (it's been a while), but here's an example of how to get network drive free space:

http://en.csharp-online.net/Network_Drive_Free_Space

I think replacing 'name' with 'VolumeName' in that example will give you what you need.

WMI reference here just in case:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394173(VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Never use WMI
Use net apis.